# What is your experience with auditing features (Oracle)?

Tags: database, oracle

Did you ever use Oracle auditing features on a production db?

How did that impact on performances, and are there differences you noticed between different versions of Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfomance-wise, you'd need to auditing a hell of a lot of information for Oracle 10.2 FGA to be a significant problem. I haven't used earlier versions or 11g.

Even simply for manageability reasons, you need to look at auditing only pertinent information... From the top of my head, I don't see why CPU/IO utilization would ever go more than a few percent over normal utilization for most enterprise applications.